# AS3 or PHP - How to filter an array with multiple values from another array?

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, filter

Can anyone please help me with this. Imagine you have an Indexed array that lists wines and each wine has a name, manufacture, country of origin, price, and a year.

```
var wines:Array = new Array(); 
wines = [ 

{winename:"Baron des Lougres", country:"France", year:"2008", price:"20.00", manufacture:"Le Yeats"},

{winename:"Barefoot Sauvignon", country:"USA", year:"2012", price:"12.00", manufacture:"Big Vines"},

]
```

Obviously with more wines in the indexed array/database.

I would like users to be able to filer, for example, a manufacture, year and then select a number of countries (Chili, Argentina, USA). I would have to filter the wines array with an array of selected countries. I know how to sort the main array with set values using && in the if filtering but I don't know how to use it with dynamic values. The country sort could have 1 to 10 or more values, it's length would be dynamic. I want to have over 2000 wines in the array/database, so I would like a nice neat code CPU lite as possible.

The values returned would only be from the countries selected. Is it possible to write an IF statement with an array as a condition or do I have to do it another way?

Something like:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < wines.length; i++) 
    if (wines.year == selected_year 
&& wines.manufacture == selected_manufacture
&& wines[i].country == selected_countries_array)
{
    trace(wines[i].name);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

The answer below, from bwroga worked. It looks a bit different from the code above but that is only because I edited this question after he answered it. But his code, the indexOf part works perfect. Thank you bwroga. I tried the following and it worked! :)

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < wines.length; i++) 
    if (wines.year == selected_year 
&& wines.manufacture == selected_manufacture
&& selected_countries_array.indexOf(wines[i].country != -1)
{
    trace(wines[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do the items (wines) come from? If it's a database, that's the right place to filter results. Also the only line of code you've provided is not enough to suggest you good solution.

Comment: Hi Veseliq. I added more information as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// Actionscript
if(year == selected_year && 
   manufacture == selected_manufacture && 
   selected_counties_array.indexOf(country) !== -1
){
//action
}
```

If the country is in selected_countries_array, indexOf would return the index of the country in the array. If it is not in the array, it returns -1.

In PHP, you would do this:

```
// Php
if($year == $selected_year && 
   $manufacture == $selected_manufacture && 
   in_array($country, $selected_counties)
){
//action
}
```